# Wavenumber where $k=0$

Tags: fourier-transform

What is the significance of wavenumber $k=0$, especially with respect to Fourier transformations? In that case, the Fourier coefficient would not consist of any imaginary components, but is there something more fundamental to this? Perhaps a sort of ground state?